# Which Hyperviser Solution for Java Applications?

Tags: linux, virtualization, java, hypervisor

Do you have any comment which of the available hypervisor solutions is best suited for Java applications? i.e. provides higher performance along with Java virtual machine?

Our machines are mid-level 64b Intels. Running Ubuntu Linux (8.04-LTS) and Sun JVM 1.6.0. Our applications are Network and Disk I/O oriented.

Answer (score 1):

We run a java / JBoss stack and recommend all our new clients deploy on KVM.  We setup a very minimal host machine and then will load 4GB to 16GB KVM instances.

Around the time RHEL 5.5 and CentOS 5.5 came out we began to see huge gains in performance on par with VMware and better than Xen in most case.

Best part is KVM is "free" on Ubuntu and CentOS.